# How to configure Lubuntu for arcade machine?

Tags: lubuntu, games, emulation, mame

Good morning people
Could you help me turn a Lubuntu installation into an arcade machine setup?
I am from windows and I have been caught with Lubuntu, several alerts appear when I am playing, I am already able to remove the splash screen from startup, but the splash screen when I turn off Lubuntu I still haven't been able to.
But the idea is to use the Lubuntu operating system to use the AttractMode game emulator along with MAME to play on an arcade controller that the person does not realize is behind Lubuntu.
The items I most need in the nomination:
-remove the lubuntu finishing splash screen;
-Stop with lubuntu alerts or any on-screen message to the user;

- Do not show the lubuntu menu bar while in the game emulator;
  -Don't show the mouse;

Well, these are some items that have kept me awake, rss
Thanks in advance